# Attribute android is not allowed here and show this message "Error:(42) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Some attribute(same) of Two project show in figure. The right side project okay, but left side project show error

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPMXK.jpg)

Comment: the image right side is of the `debug\Manifest.xml` as you can see. No need to specify `versionCode` and `versionName` in AndroidManifest.xml file as you already have them in your `build.gradle`. **So remove them from your project `AndriodMainfest.xml` file**. Go to mainfest folder open the file and remove the two lines of `versionCode` & `versionName`..!!

Comment: But  
android:screenOrientation & android:launchMode also show error inside <activity> </activity> tag

Comment: post your current manifest file in question **not IMAGE**.. I am taking about code..!!

Answer (score 0):

For your `"attribute not allowed here"` problem, `versionCode`, `versionName`  have to be placed in the `build.gradle` file and not in the Android Manifest. That should solve the problem

### UpDate :

remove this line from `manifest.xml` file.

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

Comment: At the image at right side another project showing no error .  why?

Comment: @Harunduet it is because you are missing something or you have add any extra character so that this error is error instead of posting Image first post the code here.

Comment: @Harunduet go to File and select Option `Invalidate Caches and Restart` and select `Restart` I think if you are doing any mistake then then it could solve your probelm..

Comment: <activity
            android:name="elections.usa.inc.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: android:screenOrientation   &  android:launchMode  also show error inside  <activity>   </activity>   tag.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The project is assigned me by one of my client. I think some of code in menifest file is coppied from another resources, as a result special character or whitespace was present in that file which is invisible.  when ever I remove all of the comments and extra space then its okay now.

Comment: So, whenever need to copy some code from other resource like internet or something else then first paste the contents in a notepad++ like editor and see carefully all the special character, white-space and then after rectifying paste in to the desired file.